# how matlab pack negative number as int16

Tags: matlab, binary, numbers

how matlab pack negative number as int16 like -22 ?

for positive number I notice that when we have 4 digits number it pack it like this :

the numbers is : 1254
matlab pack it as 230 and 4 then if you convert these numbers to binary we will have 11100110 for 230 and 100 for 4 . now you can convert it to normal format like this :

```
>> bin2dec('10011100110')

ans =

       1254.00
```

now  how it works for negative number ? ( when it packed -22 to int16 it convert to 234 and 255 )

Comment: its the [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to do the conversion in both directions:

```
%# convert from int16 to binary
>> dec2bin(typecast(int16(-22),'uint16'))
ans =
1111111111101010

%# convert from binary representation to int16
>> typecast(uint16(bin2dec('1111111111101010')),'int16')
ans =
    -22
```